# Transform dataframe to get co-author relationships

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame of authors and their papers:

```
     author paper
0      A     z
1      B     z
2      C     z
3      D     y
4      E     y
5      C     y
6      F     x
7      G     x
8      G     w
9      B     w
```

I want to get a matrix of how many papers each pair of authors has together.

```
   A B C D E F G
A   
B  1  
C  1 1  
D  1 0 1  
E  0 0 1 1 
F  0 0 0 0 0 
G  0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Is there a way to transform the DataFrame using pandas to get this results? Or is there a more efficient way (like with numpy) to do this so that it is scalable?

Comment: Is this question simply a variant of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467429/pairwise-matrix-from-a-pandas-dataframe)?

Comment: Seems so, though I can't quite figure out how to adapt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_dummies`, which I first reached for, isn't as convenient here as hoped; needed to add an extra `groupby`.  Instead, it's actually simpler to add a dummy column or use a custom aggfunc.  For example, if we start from a `df` like this (note that I've added an extra paper `a` so that there's at least one pair who's written more than one paper together)

```
>>> df
   author paper
0       A     z
1       B     z
2       C     z
[...]
10      A     a
11      B     a
```

We can add a dummy tick column, pivot, and then use the "it's simply a dot product" observation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467429/pairwise-matrix-from-a-pandas-dataframe):

```
>>> df["dummy"] = 1
>>> dm = df.pivot("author", "paper").fillna(0)
>>> dout = dm.dot(dm.T)
>>> dout
author  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
author                     
A       2  2  1  0  0  0  0
B       2  3  1  0  0  0  1
C       1  1  2  1  1  0  0
D       0  0  1  1  1  0  0
E       0  0  1  1  1  0  0
F       0  0  0  0  0  1  1
G       0  1  0  0  0  1  2
```

where the diagonal counts how many papers an author has written.  If you really want to obliterate the diagonal and above, we can do that too:

```
>>> dout.values[np.triu_indices_from(dout)] = 0
>>> dout
author  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
author                     
A       0  0  0  0  0  0  0
B       2  0  0  0  0  0  0
C       1  1  0  0  0  0  0
D       0  0  1  0  0  0  0
E       0  0  1  1  0  0  0
F       0  0  0  0  0  0  0
G       0  1  0  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with several thousand authors? Pivoting the `df` causes puts an unmanageable strain on memory