# More elegant computation of zscore of column differences in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, bioinformatics

I have a `n x m` DataFrame quantifying the expression of `n` genes in `m` areas. I want to calculate the number of genes differentially expressed between all pairs of areas.

```
               Area                             Area
 Gene    A     B     C            Area    A    B    C             
  a                                 A 
  b                      -->        B     x
  c                                 C
```

In the above sketch, x denotes the number of genes common to regions `A` and `B` that are enriched in area `B`.  **I need to calculate the zscores of all pairwise column differences.**

**Current approach**

```
def compare(one,two):
     column_one_header,column_one_data = one
     column_two_header,column_two_data = two
     zscores =  zscore(column_one_data-column_two_data)
     return len(zscores[zscores>threshold])


 heatmap = [[compare(column_one,column_two)
             for column_one in df.iteritems()]
             for column_two in df.iteritems()]
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467429/pairwise-matrix-from-a-pandas-dataframe) suggests that there is a simpler and faster way to do this. In contrast to that question, I want to do multiple operations. I'm not sure how to write a similar one-liner for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(random_integers(0,100,(3,3)),columns=list('ABC'),index=list('abc'))


differ = reshape([sum(df[col2]-df[col]) for col2 in df for col in df], (3,3))
differ = pd.DataFrame(differ, columns=list('ABC'),index=list('ABC'))

differ
```

you can still use your own function where this calls sum(a-b). Note that we're letting Pandas handle applying the functions series-wise, which is generally more elegant.

Comment: Elegant certainly. Weirdly, not faster. Bottleneck is in the function I define though.

Comment: You're looking about at the amazing concatenations of pandas' built-ins? because I believe a lot of them are well-optimized.