# Extracting data from a row to row comparison in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm having an issue with pandas (again), here it is:

I have one huge dataframe, let's summarize it by:

```
     id      categories
0    id_1    cat_1
1    id_1    cat_2
2    id_2    cat_2
3    id_2    cat_1
4    id_3    cat_1
5    id_3    cat_1
6    id_3    cat_3
```

(seems huge doesn't it? And the code to create it:)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['id_1','cat_1'],['id_1','cat_2'],['id_2','cat_2'],['id_2','cat_1'],['id_3','cat_1'],['id_3','cat_1'],['id_3','cat_3']],columns = ['id','cat'])
```

And from this I would like to create a dataframe containing for each category the number of clients who bought in the two categories.

I will then get:

```
     categories1    categories2    amount
0    cat_1          cat_1          3
1    cat_1          cat_2          2
2    cat_1          cat_3          1
3    cat_2          cat_1          2
4    cat_2          cat_2          2
5    cat_2          cat_3          0
6    cat_3          cat_1          1
7    cat_3          cat_2          0
8    cat_3          cat_3          1
```

Which I can then change to a matrix with categories as index and columns with a pivot (if I can do the matrix, without this temporary dataframe, I'd be happy to learn how).

The problem is I can't get this dataframe done without looping on my rows, which is extremely long! (even doing it with a little cleverness, like using the symmetry, or using a groupby for cat_i / cat_i rows, etc...).

EDIT: If I can build a matrix categories/id filled with 0 and 1 for labelling if id_i bought in cat_j, I can then produce the wanted matrix following this method: [Pairwise matrix from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467429/pairwise-matrix-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) for creating all combination with column `cat` by `id`, [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and with `groupby` aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = pd.merge(df,df, on='id').drop_duplicates()
print df1
      id  cat_x  cat_y
0   id_1  cat_1  cat_1
1   id_1  cat_1  cat_2
2   id_1  cat_2  cat_1
3   id_1  cat_2  cat_2
4   id_2  cat_2  cat_2
5   id_2  cat_2  cat_1
6   id_2  cat_1  cat_2
7   id_2  cat_1  cat_1
8   id_3  cat_1  cat_1
10  id_3  cat_1  cat_3
14  id_3  cat_3  cat_1
16  id_3  cat_3  cat_3

print df1.groupby(['cat_x','cat_y']).size().reset_index(name='Amount')
   cat_x  cat_y  Amount
0  cat_1  cat_1       3
1  cat_1  cat_2       2
2  cat_1  cat_3       1
3  cat_2  cat_1       2
4  cat_2  cat_2       2
5  cat_3  cat_1       1
6  cat_3  cat_3       1
```

Comment: Are `0` values important in column `amount`?

Comment: It depends on the way 'pivot' deals with missing values, but I think it might empty with NaN which can then easily be replaced by zeros. Your solution seems to work, I will look it closely, thanks a lot! (And I won't forget to accept it if it prooves to be fitting of course)

Comment: Thank you, no problem. Yes, by pivot you get `NaN`, so it can works very well.

Comment: Well, my dataframe 'df' being 17M rows long, it stills seems to be too long.. Isn't there a faster way? Maybe not passing by this temporary dataframe and going right to the output matrix (the one pivot should give me).

Comment: Unfortunately I have no other idea.